# ADD MAX function after ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY PO_Number, PO_Value, Supplier 
                             ORDER BY Date_PurchaseOrder) AS Line_Count, 
         * 
     FROM 
         Table_PO) AS T 
WHERE
    Line_Count = 1
```

It returns the `Line_Count` accordingly. But instead of the `WHERE` clause, I would like to use a `MAX` function to return only the highest counts. I tried a few samples but didn't work.

I need to get use the highest `Date_PurchaseOrder` and disregard the other dates.

As a `PO_Number` can have multiple `Date_PurchaseOrder`, I need only the last date in the column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Im running SQL Server.

Comment: The highest Date_PurchaseOrder in the table, or highest by PO_Number? (or by PO_Number, PO_Value, Supplier?)

Comment: ORDER BY Date_PurchaseOrder DESC will give you the most recent date in the row_number = 1 position.  This way you don't need MAX and you don't care how many entries the orders have, the one you want will always be in the same row_number position.

Comment: FYI, MAX has also a window version. MAX(column) OVER (...)

Answer (score 1):

Use `subquery` instead :

```
select tp.*
from Table_PO tp
where Date_PurchaseOrder = (select max(Date_PurchaseOrder)
                            from Table_PO tp1
                            where tp1.PO_Number = tp.PO_Number
                           );
```

However, you can also use `dense_rank()` function :

```
select *
from (select *, dense_rank() over (partition by PO_Number 
                                        order by Date_PurchaseOrder desc) as Seq
      from Table_PO 
     ) tp
where Seq = 1;
```

**EDIT :** Just do order by `DESC`

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PO_Number, PO_Value, Supplier 
                                     ORDER  BY Date_PurchaseOrder DESC) AS Line_Count
      FROM Table_PO 
      ) AS T 
Where Line_Count = 1;
```

Comment: Slight nit pick - I think if there can be ties he'd want to use Rank rather than Row_Number to get the same result as the correlated subquery.

Comment: @Error_2646. . . Yes if we go with first version then second should have `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Yogesh, thanks for your reply. I still get duplicates with both - subquery and dense rank. My goal is after I run the Row_Number is to identify the # of rows it returns and only display the highest count. 

My output after I run the posted query:

POrder  POValue   Supplier  Line Count    Date_Pur_Oder
12345    1000,00        Test                   1       05/20/2018
12345    1000,00        Test                   2       05/22/2018
12345    1000,00        Test                   3       05/23/2018
12345    1000,00        Test                   4       05/24/2018

Comment: @Yogesh,   

My output after I run the my initial - posted query:

    POrder  POValue   Supplier  Line Count    Date_Pur_Oder
    12345    1000,00        Test                   1       05/20/2018
    12345    1000,00        Test                   2       05/22/2018
    12345    1000,00        Test                   3       05/23/2018
    12345    1000,00        Test                   4       05/24/2018

I need to display only the row for count 4 in this case. It can be 10, 1 or 100 depending on the PO. 

Thanks

Comment: @YogeshSharma It looks it ran as a charm!! thanks for all your help!!